# Take Video shortcut fails to save the video if longer than 2 minutes

Tags: iphone, video, shortcuts-app

I've got an issue with saving a video if the video camera is started via a shortcut. The video is saved to Photos if the video is shorter than 2 minutes, but something fails to save the video if it is more than 2 minutes long. I don't know if it fails to save due to the shortcut or the video system itself.

I created a Shortcut that runs:

1. Turn Airplane Mode On
2. Take Video with Back Camera
3. Save Video to Recents
4. Turn Airplane Mode Off

I run the shortcut and and video starts, and when I stop the video by touching the red button, the video can be saved with "Use Video."

For videos shorter than ~ 2 minutes, the video saves to Photos. With a video longer than 2 minutes, the video won't save. Saving *appears* to work when touching "Save Video", but the error message "There was a problem running the shortcut" appears a few seconds later on the home screen, the video hasn't saved, and Airplane Mode has stayed on.

This is on an iPhone 6S with 32GB RAM and iOS 14.8. Any ideas?

Comment: This may be related to a setting for Shortcuts : Setting / Shortcuts / Advanced / Allow Sharing Large Amount of Data.  BTW I tested without this setting on iPhone 12 mini and I could do and run the Shortcut with a 3 minutes video with no problem. It may be related to physical memory of device ?

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. I don't have "Allow Sharing Large Amount of Data", but there was an iCloud sync option, which I turned off. Is "Allow Sharing Large Amount of Data" only on iOS 15? I have 32GB, 18GB free; and a 1 minute video is 100 MB. Still won't save a 2 minute+ video. But I can take a video 10 minutes long when manually starting the camera.

Comment: May be a iOS15 option only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iOS 15 update fixes this issue (bug or feature); now I can take 5+ minute videos, and they sucessfully save and Airplane mode toggles off again.